# Storing the last N keystrokes

Tags: c#, .net

I'm at a bit of a loss with what to do here. I want to have certain sequences of keystrokes perform certain actions.

I basically need to store the last N keystrokes, and when a key is pressed, look for a sequence that matches the most recent keystrokes.

So say I have 2 sequences:

```
yes
no
```

and as I type, my keystroke history looks like this:

```
a
ab
abc
abcn
abcno
```

at which point it should recognize the sequence `no` and perform the appropriate action.

It will also need to work with sequences such as:

```
year
yell
```

and input such as:

```
yeayell
```

Key sequences are of a finite length, so old keystrokes can be discarded, using something like a circular buffer, in this case with an optimal size of 3.

My keystrokes are represented with the `Keys` enum.

What data structure(s) or algorithm(s) should I use that will let me store the last N keystrokes and find sequences at the end?

Comment: Can you explain how to use these data structures to accomplish my goal? I just can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: Example of tracking entry of the konomi code here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469798/konami-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer, but you might want to consider a finite state machine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: @roken: Helpful, but still confusing. The solutions given no not apply to looking for multiple sequences.

Comment: Any solutions for the Reactive framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a proof-of-concept that will allow you to work with *any* collection of character sequences. I’m assuming that you’re only matching against characters (and not other keys such as `Keys.Left`).

```
// Initialize the collection of strings to be matched against here.
string[] stringSequences = new string[] { "yes", "no", "hello" };
int maxLength = stringSequences.Max(s => s.Length);

// The buffer to hold the sequence of the last N characters.
string buffer = "";

while (true)
{
    // Read the next character, and append it to the end of the buffer.
    ConsoleKeyInfo next = Console.ReadKey();
    buffer += next.KeyChar;

    // If the buffer has exceeded our maximum length, 
    // trim characters from its start.
    if (buffer.Length > maxLength)
        buffer = buffer.Substring(1);

    // Check whether the last n characters of the buffer
    // correspond to any of the sequences.
    string match = stringSequences.FirstOrDefault(s => buffer.EndsWith(s));
    if (match != null)
    {
        // Match! Perform any custom processing here.
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Match: " + match);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Adapted to work with keys.

I can’t easily test against `Keys`, so I’ve worked with `ConsoleKey` instead; however, it shouldn’t be too hard for you to translate the code.

```
// Initialize the collection of key sequences to be matched against here.
ConsoleKey[][] keysSequences = new ConsoleKey[][]
{ 
    new ConsoleKey[] { ConsoleKey.Y, ConsoleKey.E, ConsoleKey.S },
    new ConsoleKey[] { ConsoleKey.N, ConsoleKey.O },
    new ConsoleKey[] { ConsoleKey.H, ConsoleKey.E, ConsoleKey.L, ConsoleKey.L, ConsoleKey.O },
};
int maxLength = keysSequences.Max(ks => ks.Length);

// The buffer to hold the sequence of the last N keys.
List<ConsoleKey> buffer = new List<ConsoleKey>();

while (true)
{
    // Read the next key, and append it to the end of the buffer.
    ConsoleKeyInfo next = Console.ReadKey();
    buffer.Add(next.Key);

    // If the buffer has exceeded our maximum length, 
    // trim keys from its start.
    if (buffer.Count > maxLength)
        buffer.RemoveAt(0);

    // Check whether the last n keys of the buffer
    // correspond to any of the sequences.
    ConsoleKey[] match = keysSequences.FirstOrDefault(ks => 
        buffer.Skip(buffer.Count - ks.Length).SequenceEqual(ks));
    if (match != null)
    {
        // Match! Perform any custom processing here.
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Match: " + 
            string.Concat(match.Select(k => k.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this somehow be adapted for collections of `Keys`? It's got the right idea behind it. And I think you meant `buffer = buffer.Substring(1)`.

Comment: Is it `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` or `System.ConsoleKey`? (Yes, you’re right about the buffer; fixed.)

Comment: `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys`, which is nearly identical to `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. `Skip` and `SequenceEqual` are just the thing. Maybe I should brush up on my LINQ knowledge again. :)

Comment: Yes, that line is the crux of the algorithm. I strongly recommend LINQ; it performs miracles for compacting code ☺

Comment: It worked! A little note: I used a `List` and `IndexOf` to get the index of the key sequence, as I don't care about what is in the sequence, only which one.

Comment: Ok, fair enough re `IndexOf`. Glad to have helped!

Comment: The idea here is right, but this implementation will be quite slow, since `List<T>.RemoveAt(0)` is O(N). This most likely won't matter if the buffer contains at most 3 characters, but with bigger buffers, it could make a big difference.

Comment: In principle, yes. But we’re talking about user input here, which is several orders of magnitude slower than any part of that implementation, making the inefficiency negligible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) should work well.

It can reset on any input that is not following your rules.

```
enum States
{
 initial,
 y,
 e,
 s,
 n,
 o
}

if(char == 'n' && state == states.Initial)
{
  state = States.n;
}

if(char == 'o' && state == states.n)
{
  state = States.o;
}

... // etc for y, e, s - resetting to `Initial` where needed

... // Check for states o or s
```

Comment: it is not so trivial to create this kind of state machine in generic way. take for instance "nanaba" for input "nananaba"

Comment: I have more than 10 sequences, and they have many common keys. This will not work properly in that situation.

Comment: @kendfrey - This is just a simple example based on the question. A state can also be `ye`, `eye`, `odgye`. It depends on how you construct your state diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a circular buffer:

```
char[] buf = new char[3];
int pos = 0;

// on key press
buf[pos] = key;

if (buf[pos] == 'o' && buf[(pos + 2) % 3] == 'n')
    No();

if (buf[pos] == 's' && buf[(pos + 2) % 3] == 'e' && buf[(pos + 1) % 3] == 'y')
    Yes();

pos = (pos + 1) % 3;
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use it without hardcoded sequences? Something like storing each sequence as a `List<Keys>`.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and simple way for this is using [Rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the optimal, but perhaps the easiest and reusable:

Create a `CircularBuffer<T>` generic container.

This takes one parameter in the constructor, `N`, the maximum number of elements in the buffer.

The class has an array of `T` with `N` elements and an index variable, `i`, holding the index of the last added value, initialize it to -1.

`CircularBuffer` has two methods, `Add(T`) and `ToString(`).

The `Add` method increments `i`, wraps it around to `0` if `i` = `N` and stores the value at the appropriate position in the array. This should let you add values to the buffer while keeping only `N` of them in memory.

The `ToString` will output a string equivalent to the one stored in the buffer.

For `N` = 4, say you have this array:

```
                         a b c d

the indices are          0 1 2 3

the last added value is      ^

`ToString` should return 'dabc'
```

The wrapping logic here is an exercise for the user.

Every time a key is pressed add it to the circular buffer, call its `ToString` method and see if it contains the sequences you seek.