# Double characters shown when typing special characters while logging keystrokes in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, character-encoding, keycode

I have an application that logs whatever the user press, but when I press special characters like `´` with `a`, to get `á`, I get `´´a`; same thing when I want to get `à`, then i get ``` ``a ```, so all special characters get typed twice and then the regular character get typed after.

I have searched for ever and can't find anything really. But I have noticed that the problem is in the `ToAscii` method , without that the characters are typed correctly.

```
public string GetString(IntPtr lParam, int vCode)
{
    try
    {
        bool shift = Keys.Shift == Control.ModifierKeys || Console.CapsLock;

        string value = ""; 

        KeyboardHookStruct MyKeyboardHookStruct = 
            (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));

        byte[] keyState = new byte[256];
        byte[] inBuffer = new byte[2];

        DllClass.GetKeyboardState(keyState);

        var ascii=
            DllClass.ToAscii(
                MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode, 
                MyKeyboardHookStruct.scanCode, 
                keyState, inBuffer, MyKeyboardHookStruct.flags
                );

        if (ascii == 1)
        {
            char key = (char)inBuffer[0];

            if ((shift) && Char.IsLetter(key))
                key = Char.ToUpper(key);

            value = key.ToString();
        }

        return value;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? All other characters are working perfectly but it's the special characters that is coming as double chars.

---

**EDIT:**

Trying with `ToUnicode` instead.

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int ToUnicode(
    uint virtualKey, uint scanCode, byte[] keyStates, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] [Out] char[] chars, 
    int charMaxCount, uint flags);

public string GetString(IntPtr lParam, int vCode)
{
    try
    {
        bool shift = Keys.Shift == Control.ModifierKeys || Console.CapsLock;

        string value = ""; 

        KeyboardHookStruct MyKeyboardHookStruct = 
            (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));

        byte[] keyState = new byte[256];
        byte[] inBuffer = new byte[2];

        char[] chars = new char[2];

        DllClass.GetKeyboardState(keyState);

        int val = 0;

        val = ToUnicode(
                (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode, 
                (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.scanCode, 
                keyState, chars, chars.Length, 0
                );

        val = ToUnicode(
                (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode, 
                (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.scanCode, 
                keyState, chars, chars.Length, 0
                );

        if (val == 1)
        {
            char key = (char)chars[0];

            if ((shift) && Char.IsLetter(key))
                key = Char.ToUpper(key);

            value = key.ToString();
        }

        return value;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Someone PLEASE help me, I really need to figure this out `=/`.

---

**EDIT:**

```
int val = -1;

if (IsDeadKey((uint)vCode))
{
    while (val == -1)
    {
        val = ToUnicode(
                (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode, 
                (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.scanCode, 
                keyState, chars, chars.Length, 0
                );
    }
}
else
    val = ToUnicode(
            (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode, 
            (uint)MyKeyboardHookStruct.scanCode, 
            keyState, chars, chars.Length, 0
            );
```

So now I have tried calling the `ToAscii` or `ToUnicode` a couple of times to flush the real character but without success. Am I doing it wrong?

Like for ASCII, first call for `´` I get `-1`, so I call it again, then I get `1`; and then I press like `a`, to get `á`, but then I only get `a`. Same thing if I use `ToUnicode` twice after each other, I get just `a` instead of `á`, and so on ...

Comment: Keyloggers... They shouldn't even exist.

Comment: I totally agree my friend but this aint a keylogger of the kind that you think of. This is actually a school project for people that having problems of remembering usernames/passwords and with this tool they will have everything saved in a safe place.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing unsafe about keyloggers and passwords.

Comment: @syncis: So now you get it to work.

Comment: @KenKin Actually no, i havent =/

Comment: @syncis: You may ask for the question you further encountered.

Comment: Sry m8 but ur code its just not working as I want it, try this : 

If you go to notepad right now without logging and type first ´ and then a, you will get á, that's how I want it to be, logged correctly and text in notepad while logging should be correct also. When I removed the = 1 check in your code, it would log á and all those characters but in notepad it just screwed up with double accents every time I typed ´ or ` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **The myth about `ToAscii` and `ToUnicode`**

  In the question, you mentioned about that you've tried both `ToAscii` and `ToUnicode` with no success. And I also searched a question which is relative:

  [ToAscii/ToUnicode in a keyboard hook destroys dead keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964614/toascii-tounicode-in-a-keyboard-hook-destroys-dead-keys)

  I'm not saying any answer is right or wrong. However, we can think about:

  - A (not so) tricky game

    In this game, I give the player a random flipped 50 cent coin at a time. One can challenge to get one dollar bill from me, if who collected a pair of 50 cent coins with **one is a head** and **another is a tail**.

    If one gave up to challenge, then who can reserve that 50 cent, and the game restarts. If who tried but did not collect two meet the rule, then I ask to return me those I've given.

    **How can one get one dollar bill from me without losing any coin?**

  Maybe a time-travelling ..

---

Base on [[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)] on CodeProject

and my very old answer: [Konami Code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469798/konami-code-in-c-sharp/10271975#10271975)

I did some modification for answering your question.

- **Code**

  ```
  namespace Gma.UserActivityMonitor {
      using System.Diagnostics;
      using System.Windows.Forms;

      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;

      partial class HookManager {
          private static int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
              // indicates if any of underlaing events set e.Handled flag
              bool handled=false;

              if(nCode>=0) {
                  // read structure KeyboardHookStruct at lParam
                  var MyKeyboardHookStruct=
                      (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));

                  // raise KeyDown
                  if(s_KeyDown!=null&&(wParam==WM_KEYDOWN||wParam==WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) {
                      Keys keyData=(Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.VirtualKeyCode;
                      KeyEventArgs e=new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
                      s_KeyDown.Invoke(null, e);
                      handled=e.Handled;
                  }

                  // raise KeyPress
                  if(s_KeyPress!=null&&wParam==WM_KEYDOWN) {
                      var keyText=GetString(lParam, nCode, ref handled);

                      if(""!=keyText) {
                          var keyChar=keyText.First();
                          Debug.Print("keyText => {0}", keyText);

  #if false
                          if(AccentFormatter.Combination.Values.Contains(keyChar)) {
                              SendKeys.Send("\b"+keyText);
                              return -1;
                          }
  #endif
                      }
                  }

                  // raise KeyUp
                  if(s_KeyUp!=null&&(wParam==WM_KEYUP||wParam==WM_SYSKEYUP)) {
                      Keys keyData=(Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.VirtualKeyCode;
                      KeyEventArgs e=new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
                      s_KeyUp.Invoke(null, e);
                      handled=handled||e.Handled;
                  }
              }

              // if event handled in application do not handoff to other listeners
              if(handled)
                  return -1;

              // forward to other application
              return CallNextHookEx(s_KeyboardHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
          }

          public static String GetString(IntPtr lParam, int vCode, ref bool handled) {
              var MyKeyboardHookStruct=
                  (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));

              bool isDownShift=((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)&0x80)==0x80?true:false);
              bool isDownCapslock=(GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)!=0?true:false);

              byte[] keyState=new byte[256];
              GetKeyboardState(keyState);
              byte[] inBuffer=new byte[2];

              var keyText="";

              var ascii=
                  ToAscii(
                      MyKeyboardHookStruct.VirtualKeyCode,
                      MyKeyboardHookStruct.ScanCode,
                      keyState, inBuffer, MyKeyboardHookStruct.Flags
                      );

              if(ascii==1) {
                  char key=(char)inBuffer[0];

                  if((isDownCapslock^isDownShift)&&Char.IsLetter(key))
                      key=Char.ToUpper(key);

                  KeyPressEventArgs e=new KeyPressEventArgs(key);
                  s_KeyPress.Invoke(null, e);
                  handled=handled||e.Handled;

                  keyText=new String(new[] { e.KeyChar });
                  var sequence=KeySequence.Captured(e.KeyChar);

                  if(null!=sequence)
                      keyText=sequence.ToString(AccentFormatter.Default);
              }

              return keyText;
          }
      }

      public class KeySequence {
          public String ToString(IFormatProvider provider) {
              return
                  null==provider
                      ?new String(Sequence.Select(x => (char)x).ToArray())
                      :String.Format(provider, "{0}", Sequence);
          }

          public override String ToString() {
              return this.ToString(default(IFormatProvider));
          }

          public bool Captures(int keyValue) {
              for(var i=Sequence.Length; i-->0; ) {
                  if(Sequence[i]!=keyValue) {
                      if(0==i)
                          Count=0;

                      continue;
                  }

                  if(Count!=i)
                      continue;

                  ++Count;
                  break;
              }

              var x=Sequence.Length==Count;
              Count=x?0:Count;
              return x;
          }

          public KeySequence(int[] newSequence) {
              Sequence=newSequence;
          }

          public static KeySequence Captured(int keyValue) {
              return m_List.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Captures(keyValue));
          }

          public int Count {
              private set;
              get;
          }

          public int[] Sequence {
              set;
              get;
          }

          static KeySequence() {
              m_List.AddRange(
                  from x in AccentFormatter.Combination.Keys
                  let intArray=x.Select(c => (int)c).ToArray()
                  select new KeySequence(intArray)
                  );
          }

          static readonly List<KeySequence> m_List=new List<KeySequence>();
      }

      public class AccentFormatter: IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {
          String ICustomFormatter.Format(String format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider) {
              return GetAccent(new String((arg as int[]).Select(x => (char)x).ToArray()));
          }

          object IFormatProvider.GetFormat(Type formatType) {
              return typeof(ICustomFormatter)!=formatType?null:this;
          }

          public static String GetAccent(String input) {
              return
                  Combination.Keys.Contains(input, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      ?Combination[input].ToString()
                      :"";
          }

          static AccentFormatter() {
              AcuteSymbol=((char)0xb4).ToString();
              GraveSymbol=('`').ToString();

              var ae=(char)0xe6;
              var oe=(char)0xf8;
              AcuteCandidates="acegiklmnoprsuwyz".ToArray().Concat(new[] { ae, oe }).ToArray();
              GraveCandidates="aeinouwy".ToArray();

              var lowerAcuteAccents=(
                  new[] { 
                      0xe1, 0x107, 
                      0xe9, 0x1f5, 
                      0xed, 0x1e31, 0x13a, 0x1e3f, 0x144, 
                      0xf3, 0x1e55, 0x155, 0x15b, 
                      0xfa, 0x1e83, 0xfd, 0x17a, 
                      0x1fd, 0x1ff
                  }
                  ).Select(
                      (x, i) => new {
                          Key=AcuteSymbol+AcuteCandidates[i],
                          Value=(char)x
                      }
                      );

              var upperAcuteAccents=(
                  new[] { 
                      0xc1, 0x106, 
                      0xc9, 0x1f4, 
                      0xcd, 0x1e30, 0x139, 0x1e3e, 0x143, 
                      0xd3, 0x1e54, 0x154, 0x15a, 
                      0xda, 0x1e82, 0xdd, 0x179, 
                      0x1fc, 0x1fe
                  }
                  ).Select(
                      (x, i) => new {
                          Key=AcuteSymbol+char.ToUpper(AcuteCandidates[i]),
                          Value=(char)x
                      }
                      );

              var lowerGraveAccents=(
                  new[] { 0xe0, 0xe8, 0xec, 0x1f9, 0xf2, 0xf9, 0x1e81, 0x1ef3 }
                  ).Select(
                      (x, i) => new {
                          Key=GraveSymbol+GraveCandidates[i],
                          Value=(char)x
                      }
                      );

              var upperGraveAccents=(
                  new[] { 0xc0, 0xc8, 0xcc, 0x1f8, 0xd2, 0xd9, 0x1e80, 0x1ef2 }
                  ).Select(
                      (x, i) => new {
                          Key=GraveSymbol+char.ToUpper(GraveCandidates[i]),
                          Value=(char)x
                      }
                      );

              Combination=
                  lowerAcuteAccents
                      .Concat(upperAcuteAccents)
                      .Concat(lowerGraveAccents)
                      .Concat(upperGraveAccents)
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
          }

          public static readonly Dictionary<String, char> Combination;
          public static readonly String AcuteSymbol, GraveSymbol;
          public static readonly char[] AcuteCandidates, GraveCandidates;
          public static readonly AccentFormatter Default=new AccentFormatter();
      }
  }
  ```

  First off, with the code downloaded from CodeProject, find `HookManager.Callbacks.cs` and **delete the whole method** `KeyboardHookProc`.

  Then You can save the code above in a new file such like `HookManager.Modified.cs` and add it in project `Gma.UserActivityMonitor`, or just paste it at the rear of `HookManager.Callbacks.cs`.

  Remember to set `Gma.UserActivityMonitorDemo` as **startup project**. It was set target framework to 2.0, and you might want to set to a higher.
- **Input → Output**

  [image: Vmh1A.jpg]
- **About the accent**

  As I searched there are two kind of general accent, they are [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) and [acute accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent). 
  The diacritic of acute accent is `´`, and the possible letters are `áǽćéǵíḱĺḿńóǿṕŕśúẃýź`. 
  The diacritic of grave accent is `` `, and the possible letters are`àèìǹòùẁỳ`.

  Both of them are possible in upper case or lower case, but I did not find an easy enough way works with them in classes those are built-in of the framework. For example, I cannot use `ToUpper` or `ToLower` to get a opposite case with `Ǹ` and `ǹ`, I even tried `ToUpperInvariant` and `ToLowerInvariant`. Thus I choose to use a hard-coded sequence in `AccentFormatter`, and you may change it to reading from files, or implement another custom formatter yourself.
- **Array arrangement of hexadecimal representation**

  In the code, I arranged the acute accent sequence as:

  ```
  0xc1, 0x106, 
  0xc9, 0x1f4, 
  0xcd, 0x1e30, 0x139, 0x1e3e, 0x143, 
  0xd3, 0x1e54, 0x154, 0x15a, 
  0xda, 0x1e82, 0xdd, 0x179, 
  0x1fc, 0x1fe
  ```

  which is:

  ```
  ÁĆ
  ÉǴ
  ÍḰĹḾŃ
  ÓṔŔŚ
  ÚẂÝŹ
  ǼǾ
  ```

  The `Ǽ` and `Ǿ` are put at the rear because `Æ` and `Ø` do not have a corresponding character in ASCII(non-extended).

  I preferred to save the code in ANSI with a default code page, since I have a different `CultureInfo` from the languages which is in alphabet. And you might want to change them to exact characters for readability.
- **Send keys to the active application**

  If you want to send the key to the active application, then do the following change in the code:

  change

  ```
  #if false
  ```

  to

  ```
  #if !false
  ```

  Inside the conditional compilation block, the code fragment is

  ```
  if(AccentFormatter.Combination.Values.Contains(keyChar)) {
      SendKeys.Send("\b"+keyText);
      return -1;
  }
  ```

  It use a backspace character to erase the previous typed `` `or`´` once it recognized as a specific combination. Backspace here is the time machine ..

After this demo, I guess you'll know how to modify them to merge in your code.

Comment: +1 thanks for sharing. I did a bunch of research and found many people getting stuck on this.

Comment: Í cant get it to work, still getting the a without the á. What am I doing wrong, I am using the exact project that you mentioned and upgraded both projects to 4.0 and they still wont work.

Comment: Yea i think i got ur idea right now, very good my friend, very good! I think actually I can somehow make this work with my application because I am receiving the á now.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Thank you. But I'm not sure *stuck on this* means *global hook* or *capture specific key sequence* ..

Comment: I noticed the same problem now, it works within the application but when I am logging and writing in notepad, I will get ´´a ... back to scratch 1 :( Maybe changing ToAscii to ToUnicode will work?

Comment: Yea please do, but I know that the problem with the ´´a lies in the ToAscii call and not in the return value but we will see what we can find out.

Comment: Getting error at : AcuteCandidates = "acegiklmnoprsuwyz".Concat<char>(new[] { ae, oe }).ToArray(); 
Member 'string.Concat<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Sorry m8 :/ First of, with ascii == 1 , I will never get the á because once the ´ its pressed, the ascii return value ´ will never even be processed, and in notepad it still showed ´´a =/, try typing in notepad and see what you get there when you type á.

Comment: When I am logging, and opening notepad to test it, pressing ´ will result in ´´ , that means double accents. And if i press a after it will be just an a without the ´.

Comment: I am doing exactly as you are doing in your code but I am testing the logging in notepad also instead of only in the application. Problems lies in the ToAscii call, without that it wont do double accents.

Comment: @syncis: `´` cannot be ***eaten***, and cannot be blocked to wait for next character, it's a character itself. The combination can be detect when it occurs, but cannot swallow a legal character.

Comment: But how can we solve the double accents ´´ when calling ToAscii and trying in notepad?

Comment: Ok got the email. But the problems is with ur code is that the ToAscii call is made before the KeySequence.Captured code for detecting the combination, so the double accent will happen before the code that watch for combinations.

Comment: @syncis: I guess `ToAscii` would not be the critical problem, since either `ToUnicode` will fall into the same situation. I'm going to make your solution work once I recieve it.

Comment: As you can see from the first comment, the ToAscii will not return a valid value when pressing ´ but when calling ToUnicode will, and ToUnicode will also tell you that you have a "combination" as a return value, but thats the tricky part. With your return value from ToAscii and checking for only = 1 , you will only get the a without the ´ and that means without the á.

Comment: @syncis: It in fact would not be a API issue, it's a question of logic.

Comment: About the solution, you can use the solution that you provided with your code and if you can make it to log both á and not type double accents when pressing ´ , then email me the solution. I will send you an email right now.

Comment: If you go to notepad right now without logging and type first ´ and then a, you will get á, that's how I want it to be, logged correctly and text in notepad while logging should be correct also. When I removed the = 1 check in your code, it would log á and all those characters but in notepad it just screwed up with double accents every time I typed ´ or ` .

Answer (score 5):

> But i have noticed that the problem is in the ToAsciii method , without that the characters are typed correctly.

That's exactly what I was about to guess. I appreciate you having done the legwork for me! :-)

The problem is that these "special" characters are **not** ASCII characters. That is, they're actually some type of fancy-pants Unicode characters that are not part of the ASCII character set.

When you try to convert them to ASCII characters, the function presumably does the best it can, decomposing the code points that make up `á` into the separate characters `´` and `a`.

Obviously that's not what you want. You want to treat `á` as a single character, so you need to use Unicode. That's not really a problem: Windows has been all Unicode internally for at least a decade. Ditch the antiquated [`ToAscii`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646316.aspx) function; instead you'll want to use either [`MapVirtualKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306.aspx) or [`MapVirtualKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646307.aspx) to convert the virtual key code you're getting through the low-level keyboard hook into a character value.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information, but i have 1 question. There is also a method that is similiar to ToAsciii, named ToUnicode, couldnt that be something or should i try with mapvirtualkey?

Comment: @syncis Yes, you might have some luck with `ToUnicode`/`ToUnicodeEx`, but both of these methods still have problems with dead keys. One possible workaround is to call it a second time if you get a dead key (a return value of -1) the first time through. Related reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/01/19/355870.aspx

Comment: Ok lets try the first method by calling them twice, i first call it with ToAscii, and if it returns -1, i call it again right? Trying that right now and i didnt get double chars BUT i didnt get the ´ over the a, i just got the a, instead of á. Maybe mapvirtualkeyex solves this?

Comment: `ToUnicode` will solve that. Your issue with `ToAscii` is still that `á` is not an ASCII character.

Comment: Hey Cody, please check my post, i have edited now and included the tounicode code, but its still the same result. What am i missing?

Comment: I just wanted to add that calling Tounicode or Toascoo twice will result in only getting an a instead of á, so the double accent is removed but now I aint getting the accent over the a.

Comment: Your code still doesn't check return values, it just blindly calls the function twice. I strongly suggest reading the linked documentation.

Comment: Ok Check my edit now, you mean something like that? I have read the documentation and it says that i should just call tounicode until i get the right value....