# How to add konami code in a website based on html?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, background-image, mp3

I was asked to implement the Konami Code
 in a website I'm currently working on. It should do the following:

1. Change Background Image
2. Play sound
3. Bring some pop-up

What's the easiest way to achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Have you looked at Java or JQuery.

Comment: Have you looked into the [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)/[keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event? I guess you could listen for a specific key sequence and then do your thing.

Comment: Does someone know how to handle multiple cheat codes (key sequences) on the same page ?!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Place the code below in a file `js/konami.js` and reference it in the body of your html file like this: `<script src="js/konami.js"></script>`

```js
// a key map of allowed keys
var allowedKeys = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down',
  65: 'a',
  66: 'b'
};

// the 'official' Konami Code sequence
var konamiCode = ['up', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'b', 'a'];

// a variable to remember the 'position' the user has reached so far.
var konamiCodePosition = 0;

// add keydown event listener
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // get the value of the key code from the key map
  var key = allowedKeys[e.keyCode];
  // get the value of the required key from the konami code
  var requiredKey = konamiCode[konamiCodePosition];

  // compare the key with the required key
  if (key == requiredKey) {

    // move to the next key in the konami code sequence
    konamiCodePosition++;

    // if the last key is reached, activate cheats
    if (konamiCodePosition == konamiCode.length) {
      activateCheats();
      konamiCodePosition = 0;
    }
  } else {
    konamiCodePosition = 0;
  }
});

function activateCheats() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/cheatBackground.png')";

  var audio = new Audio('audio/pling.mp3');
  audio.play();

  alert("cheats activated");
}
```

EDIT: changed the sequence to b, a instead of a, b. Thanks for the comment!

EDIT 2: reset the konamiCodePosition to 0 after activateCheats was called. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Your key sequence is wrong ;D its 'b' 'a' not the other way around eheh. 
Not to be annoying but yea xD

Comment: You should set `konamiCodePosition = 0` after calling `activateCheats()` to allow consecutive execution and avoid an exception at the indexer of 'konamiCode[]'

Comment: Code will fail if input key sequence is: 'up', 'up', 'up', 'down', 'down', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'b', 'a'. Reason: on 3rd 'up', your code will correctly figure out that sequence has been broken but incorrectly set `konamiCodePosition = 0` in `else` block. Instead, it should reset to '1' in my example input since incorrect key (third 'up') is also the correct first key. @w.stoettinger

Comment: How can you prevent users from executing code more than once?

Answer (score 22):

compact version:

```js
function onKonamiCode(cb) {
  var input = '';
  var key = '38384040373937396665';
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    input += ("" + e.keyCode);
    if (input === key) {
      return cb();
    }
    if (!key.indexOf(input)) return;
    input = ("" + e.keyCode);
  });
}

onKonamiCode(function () {alert('\o/')})
```

Comment: How did you strip so much out and have it still work.? Going to talk myself through it. I see the key is the konami key code. The event listener is set. not sure what returning cb does. also what is keyCode? Sorry just trying to learn and understand how to clean up code.

Comment: Key is a string with all the key codes in it `38` for up arrow, `38384040` means up up down down, every time, when user press the key, I add the key code as a string into `input` variable. `return cb();` means: call the callback function, and leave  `cb(); return;` would be the same effect, but this is shorter. next line I check `input` is part of the `key` `indexOf` function should return `0` in our case `!` convert `0` to `true` if `input` part of the `key` we should return, and last line just reset the `input` and add the charcode to it

Answer (score 16):

My own compact and cleaned version inspired by the answers here:

```
let cursor = 0;
const KONAMI_CODE = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  cursor = (e.keyCode == KONAMI_CODE[cursor]) ? cursor + 1 : 0;
  if (cursor == KONAMI_CODE.length) activate();
});
```

In this case, the `activate()` function is called when triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Silentdrummer has a good answer. I'm not entirely sure, but I think it could end up taking up too much memory on typing intensive pages. It's good practice to reset. Either way, here's an alternative.

```
// Cheat Codes
neededkeys = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65], started = false, count = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    key = e.keyCode;
    if (!started) {
        if (key == 38) {
            started = true;
        }
    }
    if (started) {
        if (neededkeys[count] == key) {
            count++;
        } else {
            reset();
        }
        if (count == 10) {
            reset();
            // Do your stuff here
            alert('Cheat Codes Activated');
            $('body').css('background-color', '#FFA8A8');
            // Turn down for what
            var s=document.createElement('script');
            s.setAttribute('src','https://nthitz.github.io/turndownforwhatjs/tdfw.js');
            document.body.appendChild(s);
        }
    } else {
        reset();
    }
});
function reset() {
    started = false;
    count = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as a typescript module

```
const Konami = (() => {
    // up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, enter
    const SEQUENCE: Array<number> = [
        38,
        38,
        40,
        40,
        37,
        39,
        37,
        39,
        66,
        65,
        13,
    ];

    let head: number = 0;
    let isActive: boolean = false;

    let callback: Function | undefined;

    const start = (cb: Function): void => {
        if (isActive) {
            return;
        }

        window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

        callback = cb;
        isActive = true;
    };

    const stop = (): void => {
        if (!isActive) {
            return;
        }

        isActive = false;

        window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
    };

    const onKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === SEQUENCE[head]) {
            head++;

            if (head === SEQUENCE.length) {
                if (callback instanceof Function) {
                    callback();
                }
                head = 0;
            }
        } else {
            head = 0;
        }
    };

    return {
        start,
        stop,
    };
})();

export default Konami;
```

implementation:

`Konami.start(() => { alert("konami sequence entered!"); });`

**notes:** SEQUENCE is an array of the expected inputs. by using the `head` var, the order checking and number of correct inputs is maintained. it also provides a simple way to restart if input deviates from the sequence. it also eliminates the needs for a "count" var.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I came up with around 3 or 4 years ago.  In my case I chose **keyUp** to keep it separate from any actions that occur from **keyDown** events.
Also there is no need to specify what keys are allowable since the **for loop** checks which key was released against all the keys on the keyboard.

```
var konamicode = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
var kc=0; 

function checker() {
   if (kc==10) {
    // What you want to occur when code matches goes in here. 

    kc=0;  // This resets the sequence. 
    alert("It Worked!");
   }
}

function keyUp(e) {
   var keynum;
     if (window.event) { keynum = event.keyCode; }
       else if (e.which) { keynum = e.which; }
        for (i = 0; i < 222; i++) { // The 222 represents all the keys on the keyboard.

    var kx=konamicode[kc]; // kx represents the current position in the code sequence.
    if (keynum == i) {
        // Checks to see if key matches sequence,  and resets sequence if it doesn't.
        if (i!=kx){kc=0;} else {kc++;}
    }
  }
 checker();
}
```

Comment: When posting code in an answer, please make an attempt to format it properly (for example, use correct indentation) so as to make it maximally readable for others

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple version which accepts a callback function and optionally a list of key codes, defaulting to the konami code.

We demonstrate by showing the key codes as typed and reporting when a konami code is hit.  We also run another one looking for the keys "K", "O", "N", "A", "M", and "I".  (We inefficiently keep looking for our output element.  This is just for demonstration, so I don't think it matters.)

```js
const onKonami = (action, seq = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65]) => {
  const target = seq .join (',')
  let current = []
  window.addEventListener ('keydown', (e) => { 
    current = current .concat (e.keyCode) .slice (-seq.length)
    if (current .join (',') == target) {action (current)}
  })
}

onKonami (
  (seq) => {document .getElementById ('output') .innerHTML += `\nKonami code found: [${seq}]\n`}
)

onKonami (
  (seq) => {document .getElementById ('output') .innerHTML += `\nThe word Konami code found: [${seq}]\n`},
  [...'KONAMI'].map(c => c .charCodeAt (0))
)
```

```html
<p>Click here and then type</p><p>Try the Konami code (up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a)</p><p><b>Codes:</b></p><pre id="output"></pre>
<script>document.addEventListener('keydown', e => document .getElementById('output') .innerHTML += e.keyCode + ' - ')</script>
```

We keep a `current` array of the last `n` keystrokes, where `n` is the length of our target sequence.  If that sequence matches our target, we fire the callback.

It would not be difficult to pass also an event target, so we only listen when a particular element has focus.  I leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Peter's answer, so I made it namespaced and made the callback optional. I also used jquery because I like it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```js
var Konami = Konami || {};

Konami.key = '38384040373937396665';

Konami.onCode = function(callback) {
    var input = '';
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        input += ("" + e.keyCode);
        if (input === Konami.key) {
            if(typeof callback == 'undefined') {
                return alert("⬆⬆⬇⬇⬅➡⬅➡");
            }
            else {
                return callback();
            }
        }
        if (!Konami.key.indexOf(input)) return;
        input = ("" + e.keyCode);
    });
}

Konami.offCode = function() {
    $(document).off("keydown");
}

Konami.onCode();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create your own "Konami Code" add the following Code snippet in your HTML Code.
PS: Change the const secretCode to ... what ever you want :). With the current code you have to type 'arrow up' button, then 'h' then 'i' and last but not least the 'arrow down' button.

Questions? Please ask.

```
<script>
const pressed = [];
const secretCode = 'ArrowUphiArrowDown';

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
    pressed.push(e.key);
    pressed.splice(-secretCode.length - 1, pressed.length - secretCode.length);

    if(pressed.join('').includes(secretCode)) {
        console.log("Any source code that will be executed if you enter the correct code.");
    }

    console.log(pressed);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off Ehsan Kia,

I haven't seen anyone handling cases where the up key could be pressed 3+ times, and technically the code would have been input correctly.

Minified it a bit because the conditionals got long.

```
let c = 0;
const kCode = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
     c = (e.keyCode == kCode[c] ? c + 1 : (e.keyCode-38 ? 0 : (c ? (kCode[c-1] == 38 ? c : 0) : 0)));
     if(c == kCode.length) activate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
const keySequence = [];
let konamiString = '';
const konamiCode = [
  'ArrowUp',
  'ArrowUp',
  'ArrowDown',
  'ArrowDown',
  'ArrowLeft',
  'ArrowRight',
  'ArrowLeft',
  'ArrowRight',
  'b',
  'a'
];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  // To make sure it freezes the scroll when 
  // the first two keypresses are "ArrowUp"
  if (keySequence[0] === 'ArrowUp' && keySequence[1] === 'ArrowUp' && e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  const doc = document.documentElement;
  const top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);

  // This make sure it only work
  // when the window `scrollTop` is 0.
  if (top === 0) {
    keySequence.push(e.key);
    keySequence.splice(-konamiCode.length - 1, keySequence.length - konamiCode.length);
    konamiString = konamiCode.join('');

    if (keySequence.join('').includes(konamiString)) {
      // Trigger your easter egg here
    }
  }
});
```

The code also checks for the `scrollTop` of the `window` so that it won't scroll down when the first two keypresses are "ArrowUp" and the `scrollTop` of the `window` is `0`

I'm already using this code on [my blog](https://www.amitmerchant.com) without any hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the currently accepted answer does not work if user presses "up" 3 times instead of twice.

If we think about this problem, we should realize that the flaw in the approach is assuming a single "input sequence". What I mean by this is that every time the user presses the first key of the cheat code, we should consider that this might be a new input sequence.

Reflecting on this flaw, a simple solution is to keep track of multiple input sequences, not just a single input sequence. As such, all of the answers here that use a single integer `inputPosition` (or whatever it might be called) are going to be flawed*.

*To be clear, a solution could use a single integer `inputPosition` if it did some "reverse walk" check when a sequence is broken to see if a part of it could be the beginning of a new sequence, but that would be difficult to write and unpleasant to read.

So,here is my version:

```js
const keyCodesByLabel = {
  left: 37,
  up: 38,
  right: 39,
  down: 40,
  a: 65,
  b: 66
};

const konamiCode = [
  'up',
  'up',
  'down',
  'down',
  'left',
  'right',
  'left',
  'right',
  'b',
  'a'
];

const konamiKeyCodes = konamiCode.map(label => keyCodesByLabel[label]);

const activateCheats = () => {
  alert("godmode enabled");
};

var inputPositions = [];

const incrementOrRemove = (inputPositions, keyCode) => {
  return inputPositions.reduce((acc, inputPosition, i, arr) => {
    if (keyCode == konamiKeyCodes[inputPosition]) {
      inputPosition++;
      if (inputPosition == konamiCode.length) {
        inputPositions = [];
        activateCheats();
        arr.splice(1); // eject early by mutating iterated copy
        return [];
      } else {
        acc.push(inputPosition);
        return acc;
      }
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, []);
};

const handleKeyCode = keyCode => {
  if (keyCode == konamiKeyCodes[0]) {
    inputPositions.push(0);
  }
  if (inputPositions.length > 0) {
    inputPositions = incrementOrRemove(inputPositions, keyCode);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode }) =>
  handleKeyCode(keyCode)
);
```

`inputPositions` starts as an empty array.

When a key is pressed:

1. if it is the "first cheat code key" then a new element `0` is added to the array.
2. if the `inputPositions` array is not empty, the array is "reduced" to another array, whereby we either:

- discard an element whose sequence has been broken (the next required key is not the same as what was pressed) or
- increment an element whose sequence has been continued (the next required key is the same as what was pressed).

During the `reduce`, if an element equals the length of the cheat code, we know the cheat code has been successfully entered. Reset `inputPositions` to empty array, exit the `reduce` and call `activateCheats` or whatever you want to happen.

Note that this solution is more powerful than just handling the "up up up" case.

For example, imagine the cheat code is "a a b a a c". If user enters "a a b a a b", they should (rightly) expect to be able to enter "a a c" and activate cheats. But any solution that resets the "position" when sequence breaks will not catch it. More importantly, any solution that checks if pressed key is the initial key will not catch it. The only holistic solution is to have an array of input positions.

Answer (score -2):

this is my answer with using ***JQuery*** :

```
var konamiCode = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65, 13];
var emptyArray = [];

$(document).keyup (function (e){
    emptyArray.push(e.keyCode);
    if (JSON.stringify(konamiCode) === JSON.stringify(emptyArray)) {
         alert('there you go')
    }
});
```

Comment: The only thing this cheat code will unlock, is a buffer overflow. Imagine putting that on a page with a lot of user input, your "emptyArray" will be overflowing in a short period of time and of top of that "stringifying" an ever growing Array on every single keystroke is putting the nail in the coffin for your page performance.